# How to exit read-only mode

Tags: read-only-mode

I have a buffer in read-only mode.

Killing the buffer and reopening it does not do the job while restarting emacs does.

How to exit the read-only mode without restarting emacs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling `read-only-mode` toggles between read-only and edit mode for the current buffer.

You can call this via <kbd>M-x read-only-mode</kbd> or with <kbd>C-x C-q</kbd>.

Comment: This kind of discoverability is one of the things I love about emacs.

Answer (score 10):

To add a bit to @Juancho's answer, which is correct:

The default value of `read-only-mode` depends on the buffer. In particular, if it is visiting a *file*, and if the file itself is read-only, then the default value of `read-only-mode` will be *on*.

You can toggle such a buffer, as @Juancho said, to turn off `read-only-mode`.  But if you try to save the buffer after changing it you'll be prompted to confirm, like this:

```
File foo.el is write-protected; try to save anyway? (yes or no)
```

And if you answer `yes` you may be presented with an error such as this:

```
Opening output file: Permission denied, /path/to/foo.el
```

Comment: I don't observe this problem with `GNU Emacs 24.3.1`

Comment: Dunno what you mean by "this problem". But note that I said *you **may** be presented with an error such as this."* Whether you do or not depends...

Answer (score 4):

I like very much to click on the `buffer-read-only` indicator `%` in the mode line for that purpose. It is marked with a red ellipse in the following Figure.

[image]

It just feels natural to toggle the read only state where it is indicated.

Note that you can also toggle the `buffer-modified-p` flag on the right side of the `buffer-read-only` flag. This is sometimes handy when you just want to kill a modified buffer avoiding backup copies.